# Execution halted

Tags: r, pdf, latex

I'm new with R and I'm trying to make a pdf file out of a RnW file. I installed MaxTex, restarted my RStudio and tried to compile my Rnw file. For some reason it says 'execution halted' (after R loaded the librabries).

2 : echo keep.source term verbatim (label = setup, 25.3.Rnw:30)
Error in match.arg(options$results, c("verbatim", "tex", "hide")) : 
  'arg' should be one of “verbatim”, “tex”, “hide”
Calls:  -> SweaveParseOptions -> check -> match.arg
Execution halted

What should I do?

Comment: Hello LVH. It will be much easier to help you if you provide your code.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm totally new, how can I do this?

Comment: Check out this question on how to post code. [https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: At the moment I found that I had to change the Sweave preferences to knitr.